# Gremlin: How to obtain outgoing edges and their target vertices in a single query

Tags: gremlin

Given a set of vertices (say, for simplicity, that I start with one: `G.V().hasId("something")`), I want to obtain all outgoing edges *and* their target vertices. I know that `.out()` will give me all target vertices, but without the information about the edges (which have properties on them, too). On the other hand, `.outE()` will give me the edges but not the target vertices. Can I obtain both in a single Gremlin query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gremlin is as much about transforming graph data as it is navigating graph data. Typically folks seem to understand the navigation first which got you to:

```
g.V().hasId("something").outE()
```

You then need to transform those edges into the result you want - one that includes the edge data and it's adjacent vertex. One way to do that is with `project()`:

```
g.V().hasId("something").outE()
  project('e','v').
    by().
    by(inV())
```

Each `by()`-modulator supplied to `project()` aligns to the keys supplied as arguments. The first applies to "e" and the second to "v". The first `by()` is empty and is effectively `by(identity())` which returns the same argument given to it (i.e. the current edge in the stream).

Comment: Cool. Thanks! What if I want to also return just the ID of the source vertex (assuming we start with a set, not a single one)? A triple: (sourceId, edge, target).

Comment: `.outE().project('id','e','v').by(outV().id()).by().by(inV())`, right?

Comment: Yes - if you want both sides of the edge you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Figured this out.

`G.V().hasId("something").outE().as("E").otherV().as("V").select("E", "V")`

Comment: This approach works fine though `otherV()` should be reserved for traversals using `bothE()` where you aren't aware of the directionality. For `outE()` you should therefore prefer `outE().inV()`. Also, for a traversal such as this, you would probably do better to prefer `project()` as use of `as()/select()` patterns enable path-tracking which increases performance costs.